# Textfield just show my default username and password in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo the username and password that I entered into textfield but it just show my deafault username and password for phpMyAdmin and does not echo what I want.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php 

if(isset($_post['submit'])){


$username = $_post['username'];
$password = $_post['password'];

echo "HEllO" .$username; 
echo "<br>";
echo "Your password is :".$password;

}




 ?>

 <!doctype hmtl>
 <html  lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Document</title>



</head>    
<body>

<form action="form.php"  method="post">

    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">



   </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

and this a picture of what is happening:

[image: picture]

Thank you in advance for help :)

Comment: It should be `$_POST` - PHP variables are case-sensitive

Comment: Thank you very much.
the echo problem solved but why textfields still are already filled with my phpMyAdmin username and password? @RobinZigmond

Comment: Hi @nimabahar this is because you choose to save this info on your browser. Try change the browser and you see that info is not save there.

Comment: Hi @DanielArantesLoverde, thank you sir it worked on another browser, how can I fix it to work on current browser?

Comment: You need to enter in settings of this browser (i don't know what it is) and looking for saved passwords and delete it from it :) - give some vote up for help us!

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde ang again thank you :)
I'm new to stackoverflow so I need 14 more reputation to be able to vote :)
thank you anyway.